# Auto-hide window to dock to Windows taskbar or other 3 edges

Tags: html, xml, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have been tasked with developing an innovative tool this year.  My idea is an auto-hide window that, regardless of what application is being used, sits permanently snapped to the Windows desktop (to the taskbar or any of the other 3 edges) and displays content from an Oracle d/b and gives access to (and will open if not already open) web pages, PDFs, docs, etc.  It will be used by scientists doing research.  It will be a tool that will have potential general utility but will be used specifically to get immediate access to information e.g. copy a word/phrase from a Word/Excel/PDF document, open the auto-hide window and paste it into a search box there, and then click to search for it on Google, OR see something of interest in a printed magazine, open the auto-hide window, click on a preselected favorite database (being the content from the Oracle d/b mentioned above), and then go and search in that database for it.  The trouble is, I'm not a programmer and don't know where to start.  I would need to contract a programmer to do this but don't know what skills would be needed (C#, java, etc?).

My idea came to me after seeing the Snagit OneClick auto-hide window.  If anyone knows that, they should pretty well understand my idea and requirements.

Any help with identifying the type of programming required, background stuff to read, other examples of this type of auto-hide window, etc. would be most welcome!